# Trying to comprehend model::make() x model::create()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to understand the difference between the following code:

`Image::make(['path' => $path]);`

and

`Image:create(['path' => $path]);`

Relationships

```
//Image Model
    /**
     * @return MorphTo
     */
    public function imageable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

```
//Post Model
    /**
     * @return MorphOne
     */
    public function image(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
```

So, I've done a research and find the make and create explanation on the Factory section. Seemingly `make()` creates an instance of the object without saving it. `create()` creates and saves the object at once.

How the code works in the example?

Above there is the complete snippet.
On this away the code doesnt works as expected.

```
$post->image()->save(
                Image::create([
                    'path' => $path,
                ])
            );
```

It throws the exception:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'imageable_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `images` (`path`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (thumbnails/RYBkyxFLNzxwbI5eTnzx2w4QqzOfRAUj7h2SgXQM.jpeg, 2020-04-12 15:41:05, 2020-04-12 15:41:05))
```

Now, using the `make()`, it works. Without need to manually add the `imageable_type` and the `imeageble_id`. But why? This I can't understand.

```
$post->image()->save(
                Image::make(['path' => $path])
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the Factory `make()` will instantiate an Eloquent Model without persisting it to the database. Which if your unit testing or don't need to hit the database, you won't have to.

The `create()` will save that in the database, so that it can be retrieved from the database during a test.

Those can only be used with `$image = factory(Image::class)->make()` or `$image = factory(Image::class)->create()`. Do not try to use them in a controller.

Change your controller to:

```
$post->image()->save(['path' => $path]);
```

Comment: hey, I've add the exception that throws with the `create()` usage. What I can't understand is why the 'make()'  works.

Comment: First, where is that code located? In your controller or in a test?

Comment: Is at Controller

Comment: I updated my answer, try that and see if that helps.

Comment: `$post->image()->save(['path' => $path]);` won't work as well. since the `save()` is from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany` and it's waiting for a Model.

Using the create works if I pass the the `imageable_type` and `_id` values.
```
$post->image()->save(
    Image::create([
      'path' => $path,
      'imageable_type' => 'App\BlogPost',
      'imageable_id' =>  $post->id
    ]) 
);
```
Using the `make()` instead, automatically will fill the `imageable_type` and `imageable_id`. How the `_type` and `_id` is filled with `make()` it's a mistery.